# Using mdframed with inputminted

Tags: minted, mdframed

I was reading the documentation of `minted` and found out I could use `mdframed` to create a frame around my code listings using:

```
\surroundwithmdframed{minted}
```

However, I now need to create listings from source files using `\inputminted` which is not an environment.

How do I use `mdframed` with `\inputminted` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with `mdframed` is only mentioned as an alternative. Minted itself already has an option to draw frames:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\inputminted[frame=single]{python}{test.py}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
\inputminted{python}{test.py}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

or a new macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\inputframedminted}[2]{%
\begin{mdframed}
\inputminted{#1}{#2}
\end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

\inputframedminted{python}{test.py}

\end{document}
```

renaming the command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\let\inputmintedorg\inputminted
\renewcommand{\inputminted}[2]{%
\begin{mdframed}
\inputmintedorg{#1}{#2}
\end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

\inputminted{python}{test.py}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So it is no way to automatically use `mdframed` whenever an `\inputminted` command appears?

Comment: @Victor A new macro can make this automatic

Comment: Ok that's what I thought of doing but I couldn't figure it out by myself. Is there a way to renew the command but with the same name?

Comment: @Victor Yes with \renewcommand